# Can I create a schedule to run a function within my web app on Azure, and if possible passit parameters?

Tags: vb.net, azure, schedule

I am setting up a web application within Visual Studio, using VB.net.  I have a function within a class that I would like to have Azure run periodically (and ideally pass parameters to).  I have been successful in the past creating a separate project and publishing as an exe, then configuring a webjob within azure to run it on a schedule, but I'd like to try to keep all of the code within the same project if possible.  Is there a way to access the specific class/function of a web app within azure to run on a schedule?

I've done some research within Azure, and I see the options appear to be webjobs, Azure Functions or Logic Apps, but if anyone has experience and can tell me if this is possible with any of them I'd appreciate it.

Thanks in advance,

Terry

Comment: Timer-based triggers are built into WebJobs and Azure Functions.  Not sure about Logic Apps in that regard.  WebJobs can run in the same App Service as your web app while Azure Functions run in their own App Service.

Comment: Interesting, so using webjobs would I be able to call a function (public and shared) within my web app?

Comment: Your question is too broad for those site, hence my vote to close it.  This site is not to teach you how to do things from scratch.  You need to do the appropriate reading, make an attempt and then, if what you try doesn't work, post the details of the specific issue.  If you want to know how WebJobs works, read about WebJobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best option is to use the function that is triggered by time scheduling.

Here I share some links:

1. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2018/11/02/azure-functions-timer/
2. https://codehollow.com/2017/02/azure-functions-time-trigger-cron-cheat-sheet/
3. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer